# Azure Active Directory User Search Optimization

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have a query like -

```
this.adClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await GetAppTokenAsync());

var activeDirectoryResult = await adClient.Users.Where(user =>
    user.DisplayName.StartsWith(searchText) ||
    user.Surname.StartsWith(searchText) ||
    user.GivenName.StartsWith(searchText)
).ExecuteAsync();
```

to filter User from Active Directory. The query is taking time (in millisecond) like-

### Row Count =>  millisecond

Count = 100 =>  8576ms

Count = 7 =>    548ms

Count = 100 =>  1584ms

Count = 3 =>    613ms

Count = 100 =>  3374ms

& its not consistent. How can I improve/optimize the search result here?

Kindly help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say. It could be inconsistent network performance, which means there probably isn't a whole lot you can do there.

You could try storing your token (the result from `await GetAppTokenAsync()`) and reusing it. That will save you from getting a new token *every time* you make a query (it will save you a network request, and thus time). However you will have to handle getting a new token when the current one expires (depending on how long-running your application is).

Comment: Thanks Garbriel. But, GetAppTokenAsync() is taking only 2ms & its consistent